# What's the best way to separate presentation from content in iOS (like HTML and CSS)?

Tags: ios, styles

Does anyone know a good way of styling buttons, labels and other views but doing so like CSS and HTML (two separate files)? I suppose styling in each View Controller is not the best way, because if I have a button that is used in various View Controllers but have the same style in all of them, it'd be pretty hard to change this button's style (we would have to change code in each View Controller that uses it - that's far from maintainable). Any ideas? Perhaps put in a XML or in App Delegate?

Comment: I'm not sure from the body of your question so I haven't gone ahead and done it myself, but if you're not *actually* working with HTML and CSS, you should take out their tags.

Comment: You're right, this question is related to iOS only. The tags have been removed =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIAppearance proxy to customize the look of all instances of your views at once.

http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/